# Laravel - How To Upload Filetype GPX File

Tags: laravel, file, storage, gpx

I would like to upload a .gpx file to storage using Laravel. I don't want to do anything with it, just upload it. Currently trying to upload only to my local machine.

Whenever I try to do it, I get the following error: " failed to open stream: Permission denied".

I am able to upload other files, including .png and .csv files.  I am able to upload larger files than the .gpx file.

When I check the mimetype it syas "application/octet-stream".
I am unsure if this is the reason it won't upload.

Code in Form:

```
<form action="/gpxfiles" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}

<table class="table table-striped table-hover tablesorter" id="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <th>Filename</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
               File:
              <input type="file" name="gpxfile" id='gpxfile' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

Code in Controller

```
  if(request('gpxfile'))
  {
      $file = request('gpxfile');
      $mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
      $path = Storage::putFile('files\gpxfiles', $request->file('gpxfile')); //<-Fails Here
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a format that works, though I don't know why.

This code works:

```
$path = Storage::putFileAs('files\gpxfiles', $request->file('gpxfile'),'test.gpx');
```

While this code says "Permission Denied"

```
$path = Storage::putFile('files\gpxfiles', $request->file('gpxfile'));
```

And this code says "Permission Denied"

```
$path = Storage::put('test.gpx', $request->file('gpxfile'));
```

But only for gpx files.
All lines of code works for images.

Hopefully this helps anyone who stumbles upon the same problem I had.